# Получить название месяца по номеру

Tags: java, дата

Существует ли метод, возвращающий название месяца по его номеру?
То есть примерно так:

```
String nameOfMonth;
nameOfMonth = someMethod(1);
System.out.println(nameOfMonth);// January
```

Понимаю, что можно написать свой метод, но хотелось бы узнать об уже существующем.

Comment: копайте документацию, а конкретно объект Date

Comment: вот собственно страница http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Слишком сложные ответы идут. Вот вам самое простое, что можно придумать:

```
System.out.println(Month.of(1));  // Вернёт JANUARY
```

Можете локализовать так же просто:

```
Month jan = Month.of(1);
Locale loc = Locale.forLanguageTag("ru");
System.out.println(jan.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, loc)); // Вернёт Январь
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте зайти с такой стороны:

```
public Date dt;
dt = new Date(2000, 1, 1);
System.out.println(dt.toGMTString());
```

получите: `1 Feb 3900 00:00:00 GMT`.

Дальше можно взять подстроку.

Хотя для вашей задачи пожалуй будет проще написать свой метод, который по числу вернет название.

Answer (score 2):

Существует метод получить требуемое через класс [`java.util.Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) и его инстансы(см. `Calendar.getInstance()`). Далее, инстансу задаете месяц и запрашиваете [`getDisplayName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getDisplayName(int,%20int,%20java.util.Locale)) с указанием корректной локали (см. `Calendar.getAvailableLocales()`).

В классе `java.util.Date` соответствующие методы объявлены deprecated, т.е. их перестанут поддерживать в будущем, так что правильно сразу пользоваться Calendar.

Итого получится следующее:

```
String getNameOfMonth(int month, Locale locale) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    Calendar c;
    String s;
    try {
        c=Calendar.getInstance(); 
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
        s=c.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.LONG,locale);
    } catch (java.lang.NullPointerException ex) {
        s=null;
    } finally {
        // TODO finalize c
    }
    return s;
}
```

Следует учесть, что передавать желательно месяцы, преобразованные к `Calendar.JANUARY` и т.д., так как в Java эта константа равна нулю, т.е. наивный код `System.out.println(getNameOfMonth(1,locale));` вернет февраль.